# Data transfer using nServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, esb, data-transfer

Our current scenario: MyApp hosted in serverA has a batch process scheduled daily to get data from data warehouse in serverB which internally uses ETL to keep its data up to date. All are in 1 intranet.

Now we're planning to implement a ESB between applications that talk to each other like MyApp. So I would like to know if the below approach of using nServiceBus is correct and feasible for the data transfer we do:

- Have a class library defining the message contracts between myApp and
  DW endpoints.
- Have a console app for DW endpoint in serverA which publishes an event that its table is updated.
- Have a  MyAppListen console app as an endpoint in serverB that acts like a subscriber to the above event from serverA and then it sends a command an handler to update MyApp's database.
- Have a MyAppUpdate console app in serverB that takes the above command and handles it by updating the database.

If the approach is right, below are the questions I have:

1. Do I need to buy 2 standard licenses for server A and B for nServiceBus only?
2. Is there anything like a nServiceBus server which we can install in one of our servers and then all apps can send an receive messages to that server?
3. Is it ok to publish an event first and then send a command later?
4. Can the DW team publish the event using the technology they prefer, not .NET?
5. Do I need to provide serverA credentials while configuring
   MyAppListen endpoint instance to be able to connect/subscribe to DW
   endpoint in serverA?

Comment: It looks like question 4 is same as this recently asked question in SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334994/nservicebus-limitations-consumers-endpoints

Comment: Might be a good idea to contact Particular https://particular.net/proof-of-concept

Comment: Did you get this answered?

Comment: No, I did not reach out to the vendor. Switched to WSO2 which fulfilled what we wanted.